# General SDE for a Brownian Bridge

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

In this [link](http://www.randomservices.org/random/brown/Bridge.html) and in other questions here, I found that the SDE for a Brownian Bridge, $X_t$ from $0$ to $1$, is

$$
d X_t = \frac{-X_t}{1-t} d t\  + \ dW_t
$$

But what is the SDE for a Brownian Bridge, $Y_t$, from $0$ to $T$.
Is it
$$
d Y_t = \frac{-Y_t}{T-t} d t\  + \ dW_t \ ?
$$

If so, how would I go about deriving such an expression given the SDE for $X_t$?

Comment: What is your definition for a Brownian bridge from $0$ to $T$?  The link given doesn't say.

Comment: Gaussian, $Y_0 = Y_T = 0$ with expectation zero and variance $t (T-t)$. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge#General_case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if $Y$ is a Brownian bridge on $[0,1]$, then the process $W = (W_{t})_{t \in [0,T]}$ given by $W_{t} = \sqrt{T} Y_{\frac{t}{T}}$ is a Brownian bridge on $[0,T]$.  Moreover, we compute:
\begin{align*}
W_{t} &= -\sqrt{T} \int_{0}^{\frac{t}{T}} \frac{Y_{s}}{1 - s} \, ds + \sqrt{T} B_{\frac{t}{T}} \\
&= - \sqrt{T} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{Y_{T^{-1}u}}{1 - T^{-1}u} \, \frac{du}{T} + \sqrt{T} B_{\frac{t}{T}} \\
&= - \int_{0}^{t} \frac{W_{u}}{T - u} \, du + \sqrt{T} B_{\frac{t}{T}} \\
&\overset{d}= -\int_{0}^{t} \frac{W_{u}}{T - u} \, du + B_{t}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, 
\begin{equation*}
dW_{t} = - \frac{W_{t}}{T - t} \, dt + dB_{t}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: I edited the post.  You may want to check the $\sqrt{T}$ factor you're getting in the drift.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing that out.